# Pandas groupby max not returning max value for some columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The program is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
p = {'item' : ['apple','apple','orange','orange','guns','guns','guns'],'Days' : ['Mon' , 'Tue' , 'Wed' , 'Thu' , 'Fri' , 'Sat' , 'Sun'] ,'sales' : [100 , 80 , 200 , 100 , 5 , 10 , 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(p)

print(df)

x = df.groupby('item')

print(x.max())
```

But the output is:

[image: pandas groupby output]

The max day of `guns` happened in `Sat`, so why does pandas show `Sun`?

Comment: `max()` is being evaluated on all the columns. `"Sun" > "Sat" == True`.

Answer (score 2):

`max`, when called on a groupby, computes the max *per-column*. So `10` is the largest of `[5, 10, 5]`, and `Sun` is the largest (alphabetically) of `['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']`.

I think you want to use `idxmax` and `.loc`:

```
filtered = df.loc[df.groupby('item')['sales'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
     item Days  sales
0   apple  Mon    100
5    guns  Sat     10
2  orange  Wed    200
```

Comment: and what is the reason for guns to came before orange?
In the 'p' dict 'guns' are after 'orange'

Comment: @BahramShakiba See here for info on sorting: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby